# Value from query shows up as tuple in Jinja, but should be single string

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2

I have a mysql query that I'm trying to display as a string, but right now I'm get a tuple containing just the string.  Why doesn't it return just the column I asked for?  How do I get just the string?

```
kitchen_locations = <mysql select query>
# get
('myquery',)  
# want
myquery
```

```html
{% for kitchen_location in kitchen_locations: %}
    <li><a href="/{{kitchen_location}}/">{{kitchen_location}}</a></li>
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns a tuple, even if you only select one field. When you convert a tuple to a string, you get parentheses and commas. To get the desired value out, specify the first item in the tuple.

```
 <li><a href="/{{kitchen_location[0]}}/">{{kitchen_location[0]}}</a></li>
```